# Not mixed mixed content?

Tags: javascript, ajax, https

***EDIT:*** This is a public announcement: **I am a moron.** I used the `?testhttps` query string flag to prevent the HTTPS=>HTTP redirection (so that normal users would not be affected by any bugs until testing was done). The AJAX request did not have this flag and was being redirected.

---

I'm trying to get HTTPS working on my site, and while most of it is going well, AJAX is simply refusing to work:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/?testhttps' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://example.com/ajax/_heartbeat?ajax'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

But the network panel specifically says:

[image: Screenshot showing HTTPS is being accessed]

What gives? How can I fix this?

Comment: is the request you are pointing at trying to perform a redirect?

Comment: @Quince ... ... -extended silence- ............. I am a moron.

Comment: *"I am a moron."* Oh, I think we agree that it's not that, but rather that @Quince is very clever indeed and/or has been around this block (probably "and"). Nice one, Quince -- post it as an answer, this question and that answer deserve to be shared.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Heh, no, in this case it was my idiocy. See note at start of the question ;)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder nope not clever just had this exact same message yesterday and turned out an interceptor was redirecting in the middle of the request